# Cannot get attribute of an object

Tags: java, oop

I am writing a BigInteger Class to work with Big Numbers.
My BigInteger class has a String variable `number` to save the absolute value of the number and an integer variable `sign` to save the sign of this number.

Here is my function to compare 2 numbers:

```
public boolean equals(Object other)
    {
        if (other instanceof BigInteger)
            return toString().equals(other.toString()) && sign == other.sign;
        return false;
    }
```

However, when I compile, I get this error:

> java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   variable sign   location:
>   variable other of type java.lang.Object

Can anyone fix this error? Thank you

Comment: Your buildpath is wrong, How do you compile this ? Through eclipse ?

Comment: Can you post full class. So that only we can resolve

Comment: Please show the complete class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to cast `other` to `BigInteger`.

If you don't cast `other` it is considered of type `Object` that hasn't a property `sign` (exactly the error you had).

Here is the code:

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (other instanceof BigInteger) {
        return toString().equals(other.toString()) && sign == ((BigInteger) other).sign;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it is really my problem

Comment: If you find this answer useful you can flag it as the right answer with the green check.

Comment: Yeah, I have to wait 10 minutes until I can do that :)